# AWS How to send emails and notifications to individual users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

So I am making an app that monitors when food expires.

each user has a list of food and that is stored in dynamo db.

In my table I store the user's email address and when an item expires for a user.

I want to make an aws service that sends users an email and/or notification when an item is close to expiring.

I tried to make a lambda function based on https://github.com/eleven41/aws-lambda-send-ses-email
but I realize that I need to verify the emails to send notifications.

I am not sure if I am going about this correctly. What would be the proper aws setup to send user notifications in AWS?

Comment: Are you planing on adding a email verification functionality for users?

Comment: how did you finally solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that the "From:" email is under your control, two ways to do that:
1. SES --> Domains --> Verify new domain
Apply the TXT, CNAME records that are shown on your DNS
2. SES --> Email Addresses --> Verify a new email address
Enter email address
Verify this email address